# Nativescript: Add x86_64 libNativeScript.so for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript, abi

I have Nativescript-vue project.

Because of Google play 64-bit requirement I am trying to add x86_64 native code.

All resources I found while researching say to do this:

In `app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "com.foo.bar"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86', 'x86_64'
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

But `'x86_64'` is ignored the output apk's lib folder contains only this platforms `'armeabi-v7a'`, `'arm64-v8a'`, `'x86'`.

I found also [this github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4833) , Nativescript team was saying that in the next release the `'x86_64'` platform will be added, So i upgraded `{N}` , but there was no difference.

Also tried "ABI Split" config, that I found on the official {N} documentation & added `'x86_64'` to be included:

```
android {
....
  defaultConfig {
    ....
    ndk {
      abiFilters.clear()
    }
  }
  splits {
    abi {
      enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
      reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
      include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
      universalApk true
    }
  }
}
```

But also no difference.

Is there any way to achieve this manually?

Also any suggest, info, documentation will be helpful.

My config:

- minSdkVersion="21"
- targetSdkVersion="28"

Tried with "tns-android" version "5.3.1" & "6.0.0"

If you need anything else from my project/config... Tell me in the comments.

Comment: The next release (v6.0.2) is already out, why don't you try that?

Comment: The app is production ready, Deadline to publish it was yesterday, So i can't use release candidate here

Comment: It is not RC, it's GA.You may check the [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-android) repo.

Comment: Oh ok, upgraded {N} with `tns migrate` and it upgraded `tns-android` to only 6.0.0, I thaught it is the latest version that can work with Vue template, Did you know if 6.0.2 is compatible with Vue?

Comment: Yes it should be, it's a minor release only with that particular fix.

Comment: Great, it works, Maybe put this in an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android runtime v6.0.2 with support for 64bit is already out, the migrate command may not take you to the latest version of of `tns-android` always but a recent version.

You may manually update the version on `package.json` or removing and adding the platform back via CLI will take you to most latest version of the runtime.